# how to you toggle on and off a web proxy in os x from the command line

Tags: macos, networking, proxy

In OS X, you turn on and off a web proxy from System Preferences > Network > Proxies, by checking Web Proxy (HTTP) and designating the Web Proxy Server etc. and by clicking OK and then "Apply". This is way too many steps. Is there a way to do this all from the command line and a shell script?

Answer (score 44):

For an unauthenticated proxy (and assuming it's the Ethernet service you want to configure):

```
networksetup -setwebproxy Ethernet proxy.example.net 80 off
```

for authenticated:

```
networksetup -setwebproxy Ethernet proxy.example.net 80 on proxyuser "p4ssw0rd"
```

and to turn it off:

```
networksetup -setwebproxystate Ethernet off
```

If the network service isn't named just "Ethernet", you may need to parse `networksetup -listallnetworkservices` or `-listnetworkserviceorder` to get the correct name.

Comment: Shouldn't the first command end with `on` as opposed to `off`?

Comment: @mejpark The "off" and "on" keywords refer to authentication, not whether the proxy setting itself is on or off.

Comment: @AkinHwan There's probably a way to do it with `scutil`, but it's likely to be messy. Why don't you want to use `networksetup`?

Comment: @GordonDavisson in cases where i don't have admin priveleges, because it prompts me for username password

Comment: @AkinHwan Changing network settings (including the proxy config) inherently requires admin privileges. You might be able to override the network settings in specific apps (browsers, etc), but that'd depend on the app.

Answer (score 13):

To just toggle on/off my proxies in OSX Mavericks, I set up this script. Note that this example just affects my wi-fi adapter. I am toggling on/off the web, streaming, and SOCKS proxies all at once. You could set the proxy address as well, per [Gordon's example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029471/how-to-you-toggle-on-and-off-a-web-proxy-in-os-x-from-the-command-line/4029740#4029740), but I already had this saved through the System Preferences > Network > Proxies GUI.

BASH Script, saved as **prox.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

e=$(networksetup -getwebproxy wi-fi | grep "No")

if [ -n "$e" ]; then
  echo "Turning on proxy"
  sudo networksetup -setstreamingproxystate wi-fi on
  sudo networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate wi-fi on
  sudo networksetup -setwebproxystate wi-fi on
else
  echo "Turning off proxy"
  sudo networksetup -setstreamingproxystate wi-fi off
  sudo networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate wi-fi off
  sudo networksetup -setwebproxystate wi-fi off
fi
```

Then symlink the script on the command line:

```
ln -s /Script/Location/prox.sh prox-toggle
```

Now you can toggle the proxies on/off at the command line:

```
bash prox-toggle
```

Comment: @potato-eat-apple wrote: Eric Thanks for your script, one question: it always popups me to type in my machine password. How to avoid this?

Comment: I tested this and it works flawlessly. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I prepared a script named proxy that might help,

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#
#   Author: Md. Sazzad Hissain Khan
#   Date:   8 July, 2017
#
#

NETWORK_SERVICE_NAME="Ethernet"

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Argument missing [on/off]"
    exit 0
fi

if [ $1 == "on" ]; then
    echo "Enabling secure proxy for $NETWORK_SERVICE_NAME"
    networksetup -setsecurewebproxystate "$NETWORK_SERVICE_NAME" on
elif [ $1 == "off" ]; then
    echo "Disabling secure proxy for $NETWORK_SERVICE_NAME"
    networksetup -setsecurewebproxystate "$NETWORK_SERVICE_NAME" off
else
    echo "Argument invalid [permitted:on/off]"
fi
```

`NETWORK_SERVICE_NAME` is the name of your active network which you need to configure.

1. Create `proxy` file in `/usr/local/bin.`
2. Copy above script into `proxy.`
3. Set executable permission for the file using `sudo chmod 777 proxy` .

How to use:

```
proxy on
proxy off
```

Comment: Awesome. I have added networksetup -setwebproxystate "$NETWORK_SERVICE_NAME" on for HTTP proxy :)

Answer (score 3):

**Just the Toggling :)**

```
networksetup -setwebproxystate <networkservice> <on off>
networksetup -setsecurewebproxystate <networkservice> <on off>
```

Example :

```
networksetup -setwebproxystate  Wi-Fi on
networksetup -setsecurewebproxystate  Wi-Fi on
```

To handle the Modification alert : prefix `sudo` like

```
sudo networksetup -setwebproxystate  Wi-Fi on
sudo networksetup -setsecurewebproxystate  Wi-Fi on
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an Applescript that turns on and off the proxy at macworld.

- http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2003101617122867

Answer (score 2):

Enabling and Disabling Proxy with a keyboard shortcut

In terminal, you can turn wifi proxy off and on with these commands

```
networksetup -setwebproxystate Wi-Fi <on | off>
networksetup -setsecurewebproxystate Wi-Fi <on | off>
```

and Ethernet

```
networksetup -setwebproxystate Ethernet <on | off>
networksetup -setsecurewebproxystate Ethernet <on | off>
```

Here's a one-liner to toggle between on and off (Using Wi-Fi example)

```
e=$(networksetup -getwebproxy wi-fi | grep "No")

if [ -n "$e" ]; then
  networksetup -setwebproxystate  Wi-Fi on
  networksetup -setsecurewebproxystate  Wi-Fi on
else
  networksetup -setwebproxystate  Wi-Fi off
  networksetup -setsecurewebproxystate  Wi-Fi off
fi
```

**Create a keyboard shortcut that runs a shell command**

1. Start Automator, and create a new Service.
2. Set "Service receives selected: to "no input" in "any application".
3. Add an action named "Run Shell Script". It's in the Utilities section of the Actions Library.
4. Insert the bash command you want into the text box and test run it using the Run button (top right). It should do whatever the script does (off, on or toggle), and there should be green ticks below the Action.
5. Save it, giving it a service name you can remember.
6. Go to System Preferences -> Keyboard, and go to the Shortcuts tab
7. Go to the Services section, and scroll down to General - you should find your service there. If you select the line, you can click "add shortcut" and give it a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

As I needed a simple script that will just toggle both HTTP and HTTPS proxies on/off at the same time, here it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Toggles *both* HTTP and HTTP proxy for a preconfigured service name ("Wi-Fi" or "Ethernet").

NETWORK_SERVICE_NAME="Wi-Fi" # Wi-Fi | Ethernet

IS_PROXY_ENABLED=$(networksetup -getwebproxy "$NETWORK_SERVICE_NAME" | head -n 1 | grep Yes)

if [ -z "$IS_PROXY_ENABLED" ]; then
    echo "Enabling HTTP and HTTPs proxy for $NETWORK_SERVICE_NAME"
    networksetup -setstreamingproxystate "$NETWORK_SERVICE_NAME" on
    networksetup -setwebproxystate "$NETWORK_SERVICE_NAME" on
    networksetup -setsecurewebproxystate "$NETWORK_SERVICE_NAME" on
else
    echo "Disabling HTTP and HTTPs proxy for $NETWORK_SERVICE_NAME"
    networksetup -setstreamingproxystate "$NETWORK_SERVICE_NAME" off
    networksetup -setwebproxystate "$NETWORK_SERVICE_NAME" off
    networksetup -setsecurewebproxystate "$NETWORK_SERVICE_NAME" off
fi
```