# Observe any XHR request using a node process?

Tags: node.js, http

I am building a development tool, and would like to monitor requests to specific domains on a user's system.

I have already written a MITM proxy server. I would like to observe all requests to, say, `api.twitter.com`, without requiring users to change their code to point to my proxy server. This might be called an HTTP sniffer, I'm not sure.

I have considered:

- Browser plugin (eg: chrome dev tools plugin)
- `/etc/hosts` (but this can't map domain to domain I think, and if you did you wouldn't be able to get to the original one)
- Native OSX app (learning curve)

Is there a way to observe system HTTP requests using node? I don't know where to start.

Comment: Perhaps just a regular [HTTP proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy)? Although that may become problematic when trying to observe HTTPS connections.

Comment: Looks you are trying to implement a man-in-the-middle thing. Speaking about that, this tool seems promising: https://mitmproxy.org/

Comment: the mitm proxies I see require you to point your requests at them. What I really need is an HTTP Sniffer written in node. Or to use system wide settings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029471/how-to-you-toggle-on-and-off-a-web-proxy-in-os-x-from-the-command-line